# Count valid colourings on an hexagonal grid

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Tile the infinite plane with hexagons. Colour the hexagons black or white in any way you like, provided there is no line of three hexagons all the same colour. How many such colourings are there?

Obviously the answer is infinite. It increases exponentially with the area covered by the hexagons. My question is: how fast?

An altenative way to express the answer is in bits per hexagon, i.e. how much binary data can I store per hexagon on average.

### No triangles

Note that three hexagons sharing a vertex cannot all be the same colour, otherwise there will be a line of three somewhere nearby.

### Lower bound

Colour the hexagons red, green and blue such that neighbouring hexagons are coloured differently (this colouring is unique up to reflections). Then recolour the red ones black, the green ones white, and the blue ones at random. This always gives a legal colouring.

Not all legal colourings are of this special form. However, just considering colourings of this special form, the information density is $1/3$ (in bits/hexagon). This gives a lower bound on the true information density.

### Upper bound

Cut the plane into parallel strips, each two hexagons wide. Colour each strip independently of the others, avoiding lines of three and triangles. Then put them back together. All legal colourings can be made in this way.

Not all colourings made this way are legal. However, considering all such colourings, the information density is about 0.551. This gives an upper bound on the true information density.

The figure of 0.551 can be computed by considering adding one hexagon at a time to the end of a semi-infinite two-wide strip. This gives a finite state machine with four states. Counting the number of paths of length $n$ from some arbitrary initial state to each final state gives a recurrence relation: $A_n = A_{n-2} + A_{n-3} + A_{n-4}$. For large $n$, $A_n \sim 1.4655^n$, and $log_2(1.4655) = 0.551$.

**Update 2017-05-05** @mercio studied strips of width three and four and thereby found upper bounds of $0.472$ and $0.437$.

### Summary

These are all the techniques I know for studying this problem. With considerable labour I know I could improve both bounds using these techniques, but really I need a new technique. Can you help?

Comment: Interesting problem. Perhaps you'd get more attention with some alternative equivalent statement (and tags). If I'm not mistaken, what you want is to count/bound the configurations on a triangular binary lattice such that no three consecutive points (in a row ) have the same value. No need to mention "information" (or even tiling).

Comment: I can't really judge what wording/tags will get the most attention. Mine would get mine. I'm happy to accept advice. What would you suggest?

Comment: This is out of my area of expertise, but I wonder if it would help you to have an algorithm for laying out the hexagons in a spiral pattern. That way you could probably develop an algorithm for the nearest neighbors.

Comment: by considering strips of width 3 and 4, I get upper bounds of 0.472 and 0.437. I'm a bit uncertain on how to systematically improve the lower bound.

Comment: @leonbloy Thanks for putting up the bounty! Much appreciated.

Comment: @mercio Good work! That must have taken all day. I'll add your information to the question

Comment: aha of course not i have a computer and even then my stuff is not really optimized

Comment: @mercio To improve the lower bound, start from the RGB pattern. Modify it by turning large but finite contiguous areas blue in some regular pattern, leaving enough red and green between them that they don't affect each other. Then, after turning red black and green white, count how many legal ways you can colour each blue area. These ways include all those of the previous lower bound, and some more.

Comment: This might be interesting: http://www3.nd.edu/~mtns/papers/80_2.pdf

Comment: Also this http://orbit.dtu.dk/files/3970906/S%C3%B8ren.pdf

Comment: @leonbloy thanks for the references

Comment: so there isn't any example where such a density has a known closed form ?

Comment: Apparently no, even for square grids with horizontal-vertical run-length restrictions. Not that your case is equivalent to a square grid with (one direction) diagonal run-length restrictions (in addition to horizontal-vertical).

Comment: I have found a three-colour system with the same information density as my two-colour system but with a rule that only involves nearest neighbours. Is that interesting enough to write up?

Comment: The transfer-matrix approach that you and @mercio used to generate upper bounds can be modified to produce lower bounds as well.  To get lower bounds, just join the top and bottom of the strip.  You can use periodic or anti-periodic boundary conditions, with or without a horizontal shift, to obtain slightly different lower bounds.  Similarly, by counting the configurations in any region that tiles the plane... e.g., a hexagon or parallelogram... you can generate both an upper and a lower bound, by comparing free boundary conditions (upper bound) to appropriate periodic ones (lower bound).

Comment: Another note, by the way... if you apply *only* the no-triangles restriction, then you are asking for the ground-state entropy of the triangular Ising antiferromagnet.  This is known exactly (Wannier 1950), and is about $0.4881$ bits/site.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note (after the bounty expired) for the sake of future visitors:

Papers like "[Bounds on the capacity of constrained two-dimensional codes](http://orbit.dtu.dk/files/3970906/S%C3%B8ren.pdf)" (
Forchhammer & Justesen, IEEE Transactions on Information Theory, 2000) and
[On the Capacity of 2-D Constrained Codes and
Consequences for Full-Surface Data Channels](http://www3.nd.edu/~mtns/papers/80_2.pdf) (W. Weeks, 2012) and references cited therein could be a starting point. We could regard our hexagonal grid as a square grid and add run-length restrictions on diagonals.

Nevertheles, it seems hopeless to look for closed form solutions, but bounds and algorithms for estimating the capacity would be nice.